Old black and white movie: travel tubes, slave labour, nuclear plant blows up
I'm looking for a movie about a man who is testing a hibernation chamber in an underground bunker. There is a explosion (probably from a nuclear bomb), and he is dug out hundreds of years later. There is a network of travel tubes around the world. The people there travel around to save art and stuff.
Killing is not allowed. A spy (female) tells him they are looters and to come away with him. They get to her city where he finds out they use slaves for all the labour, they use pain sticks to get obedience from them. He starts a rebellion then promises her to repair their nuclear power station to help his friends escape. The plant blows up and he is told not to ever kill anyone again.
Does anyone know this movie? I thought it was like "The man from the past" but all my research gives me nothing.

It's not black and white but this sounds a lot like Genesis II (1973)

Dylan Hunt, a scientist, puts himself into suspended animation in a NASA cavern in 1979 to establish if he could be brought back to life in a couple of days to research into extending the process to astronauts. However the cavern collapses during an earthquake and Dylan doesn't recover until the year 2133. 
During the 154 years he had slept, war has broken out and the world's scientists rebelled against the war-loving military and developed a society known as the Pax, whose goal is to keep the spirit of mankind alive. 
However there are also the mutant Tyranians who plan to be Nazi-like rulers of the slowly recovering world. Dylan is tricked by the Tyranians who plan to use his knowledge of the past to rebuild their nuclear generator and therefore make their plans complete.

From Wikipedia

Hunt is accidentally found and rescued by an organization calling themselves "PAX" (the Latin word for "peace"). PAX members are the descendants of the NASA personnel who worked and lived at the Carlsbad Installation in Dylan's time. They are explorers and scientists who preserve what little information and technology survive from before the Conflict, and who seek to learn and acquire more in an effort to build a new civilization. Members of PAX find Hunt still sealed in the hibernation chamber. They revive him, and are thrilled to meet a survivor from before the Conflict.
An elaborate "Subshuttle" subterranean rapid transit system was constructed during the 1970s, due to the vulnerability of air transportation to attack. The Subshuttles utilized a magnetic levitation rail system. They operated inside vactrain tunnels and ran at hundreds of miles per hour. The tunnel network was comprehensive enough to cover the entire globe. The PAX organization inherited the still-working system and used it to dispatch their teams of troubleshooters.
He leads a revolt of the enslaved citizenry, sabotages the nuclear device, and destroys the reactor.
To Hunt's dismay, the PAX leaders assert their pacifist nature and intentions. They are attempting to rebuild an idealistic society using all that was deemed "good" from Earth's past, and they regard Hunt's interference with a rival civilization and his destructive tactics as antithetical to this end. However, they also see great good in him and value his knowledge of the past. They ask Hunt to join PAX permanently, but only if he can agree to never again take human lives. Hunt half-heartedly agrees





That's it, dang your good, thanks
